# How to apply css style for custom component in angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6, angular5, angular7

I tried to set `css` like display block to custom component but not working.I do not know how to set it.

I have given my code below. How to set css style for that? Anyone can have idea?please help to find the solution.

`app.component.html`:

```html
<my-custom-cmp  #myflag><my-custom-cmp>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```js
 @ViewChildren('myflag', {read: ElementRef}) el: QueryList<ElementRef>;

 ngOnInit(){

  this.el.nativeElement.style.display= 'block';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `@ViewChild('myflag') public el: ElementRef;` 
instead of
`@ViewChildren('myflag', {read: ElementRef}) el: QueryList<ElementRef>;`.